# Data validation with 2 conditions

Tags: conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel

I am looking for a conditional formatting formula that validates two conditions from another sheet.

I have Sheet1 and Sheet2: Sheet2 has daily records of workers such as time in and off, Sheet2 contains a list of all workers and certain dates.

I would like to find a way to color cells in Sheet1 IF 1) there is a record of a specific worker AND 2) it has the same date in the Sheet2.

Example: C4 colored orange because a record of B4 (Worker A) and C2 (11/1/2023) exist in Sheet2 (B4);
C5 colored is not colored because there is no record of Worker B on 11/1/2023 in Sheet2.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The best option here is to restructure the data on Sheet2.

Put the date in a column to the left of the Name. Like this:

[image]

If you do that, and supposing the Sheet2 were called Sheet2New, the formula for your conditional formatting rule would be some variant of (edit the range addresses as necessary):

```
=NOT(ISNA(XMATCH(C$2&$B4,Sheet2New!$B$3:$B$6&Sheet2New!$C$3:$C$6)))
```

For example:

[image]

For Google Sheets, the formula will be like this:

```
=NOT(ISNA(MATCH(C$2&$B4,ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("Sheet2New!$B$3:$B$6")&INDIRECT("Sheet2New!$C$3:$C$6")),0)))
```

If you can have the data from Sheet2 on the same sheet as the conditional formatting, you don't need to use INDIRECT.

Comment: Thank you! It worked in Excel, but not in Google Sheets. Would it be another formula for the same conditional formatting?

Comment: I've added a formula for Google Sheets. Please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Since the data is not properly **`structured`** as it should be hence, you have two options, either to **`restructure`** the data or else use **`two helper columns`** in `Sheet2` so that the **`Conditional Formatting`** can be applied in the required areas of `Sheet1`.

I am bit late as **[FlexYourData](https://superuser.com/users/1125935/flexyourdata)** Sir has given you the right way on restructuring the data and using **`Conditional Formatting`**, hence I'm opting out for the second alternative i.e. using **`two helper columns`** in `Sheet2`, which is also possible to do.

As I am not sure about your `Excel Version` and assuming there is no `Excel` Constraints as per the tags posted, then you could try the following.

[image]

---

As it can be seen two helper columns has been added on `Sheet2` far right, and applied the following formulas:

• Formula used in cell <kbd>J3</kbd>

```
=SCAN(0,B3:B9,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(ISTEXT(y),x,y)))
```

---

&,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>K3</kbd>

```
=SCAN(0,B3:B9,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(ISNUMBER(y),"",y)))
```

---

In `Sheet1` select the range <kbd>C4:I8</kbd> hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> which opens the <kbd>New Formatting Rule</kbd>, Select the last rule --> <kbd>Use A Formula To Determine Which Cells To Format</kbd> and enter the following formula in the rule description.

```
=XMATCH($B4&"|"&C$2,Sheet2!$K$3#&"|"&Sheet2!$J$3#)
```

---

Select preferred formatting fill color from the tabs and press `OK` twice.

---

If you are not using **`MS365`** then you need to use the following formulas in place of those above in `Sheet2`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>J3</kbd>

```
=IF(ISTEXT(B3),J2,B3)
```

---

&,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>K3</kbd>

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B3),"",B3)
```

---

Bothe above formulas needs to be filled down!.

---

In `Sheet1` in `Conditional Formatting` Rule.

```
=MATCH($B4&"|"&C$2,Sheet2!$K$3:$K$9&"|"&Sheet2!$J$3:$J$9,0)
```

---

All the steps for using `Conditional Formatting` remains same except the formulas are different. Please note to change the cell ranges and references as per your suit. Also, it is highly suggested to follow proper data restructuring.

---

In `Google-Sheets` the same formulas worked without needing to have an **`additional helper columns`**:

The formulas needs to be placed in `Sheet1` and needs to be filled down and filled right:

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(XMATCH($B4&"|"&TEXT(C$2,"mmddyyyy"),
 SCAN(0,Sheet2!$B$3:$B$9,LAMBDA(x,y,if(ISNUMBER(y),"",y)))&"|"&
 TEXT(SCAN(0,Sheet2!$B$3:$B$9,LAMBDA(x,y,if(ISTEXT(y),x,y))),"mmddyyyy"))),"")
```

---

- To set the `Conditional Formatting` Select the range `C4:I8`
- Goto `Format` Tab & select `Conditional Formatting`
- On selecting it opens a panel on the right hand side of the sheets, under `Format Rules` select `Greater Than` and enter `0` next.
- In the `Formatting Style` choose both `Fill` & `Text` Color as same and press `Done`. That should work on your end.
- Additionally, since the sheet is formulated, you can make the sheet `Protected` so that no one make any changes to the formulas to mess up the algorithms.

---

[image]

---

Comment: Thank you! :) Structuring data would be an easier task in my case :).

Comment: I had a SCAN solution as well, but you can't use LAMBDA functions in conditional formatting rule.

Comment: @FlexYourData Sir, I have not use the `LAMBDA()` function in `CF` I have used `XMATCH()` Function instead, but used the `SCAN()` in helper columns! You can refer in answer!

Comment: Ah yes, I see it now. Nice solution 

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, this time without restructuring data.
You should define a name (in Name Manager) and call it e.g. `result`.
Then you will define a rule for conditional formatting:
`=result`
The formula is shown in the screenshot below. Formulas in the sheet in conditional format area have been enetered only for illustration.
Solution not tested in Google Sheets.
[image: Workers List]